# Google API map-load count definition

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to save as many potentially billable **Map-Loads** as possible.

The way i call the Map is:
In an IFRAME, i do:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(...)
```

then

```
geocoder.geocode(...)
map.setCenter(..)
```

My concern is: If the user in the Main Page (outside) will enter new Addresses to seek, i would only geocode and then display that, no new map instance.

==> Will **all** of them count for **one** map-load or one for every single user-search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will count as 1 map-load. Geocoding has a separate limit of 2500 per user/day.

Comment: Thanks. So if users are only panning around, i need not to worry.  If they repeat seeking, the counter will increase :-( Thats how i understand it.

Comment: When they are panning, nothing will increase. When they are seeking(using geocoding), the user-counter for geocoding-requests will increase. This also will not have any effect to your site-specific limits for map-loads. When a user exceeds his geocoding-limit(2.5k/day), google may/will restrict the access of the user, regardless of the site he is visiting.

Comment: As by now, the geocoding-API is **limited**, but does not count for the **billable** limit. So only the respective users would be concerned? As an alternative, i could consider caching the Coordinates and do the map.setCenter() with the known location.

Comment: You are using clientside geocoding, the limits of your site are only affected when requesting the service from serverside. Caching would be nice, but is not allowed.

Comment: To get back to the original problem: there is no need to worry about the assumed user behaviour and the usage limit?

Comment: Following your description  I see no reason to care about it.